# Create class that has the same attributes as its generic but with different values

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to create a class that has the very same attributes as its generic but with different type of values?

For example:

```js
interface Project {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

class API<ApiSignature> {
   public [keyof APISignature]: Attribute;
}
```

So I would be able to do something like:

```js
const x = new API<Project>();
x.title.special_method_in_attribute()
```

Comment: You can't do this with a class *declaration*, but you could still represent such a class in the type system.  I don't know what's going on with your `special_method_in_attribute()` or how `API` is supposed to initialize its instances so that those work, but if I make up something random I get [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqe0qm). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but still helpful:

```
export interface Project {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface MySpecialType {
  doSomething: () => void;
}

export type ProjectFields = keyof Project;
export type RootGeneric = { [key in ProjectFields] : MySpecialType };

const myFunction (params: RootGeneric) {
   params.name.doSomething();

}
```